# Replacing a special character (along with space is considered same)

Tags: java, regex

Have a look at this string `String str = "first,second, there";` . there are `,` and `,` ( there's a `space` after the second comma). How do I express it in `RegEx` as `.replaceAll()`'s parameters so the
output would be :

`"first second there"`. <-- the amount on each `space` will be same.

I had tried some combinations but still fail. One of them is :

`String temp2 = str.replaceAll("[\\,\\, ]", " ");` will print `first second  there`.

Thanks before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `, *` to match comma followed by zero or more spaces and replace with single space.

```
String str = "first,second, there";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll(", *", " "));
```

output:

```
first second there
```

---

Read more about [Java Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

#### Greedy quantifiers

- `X?`  X, once or not at all
- `X*`  X, zero or more times
- `X+`  X, one or more times

Answer (score 1):

```
String temp2 = str.replaceAll(", ?", " ");
```

The ? Means optional (ie zero or once), or

```
String temp2 = str.replaceAll(", *", " ");
```

Where the * means zero or more (many) spaces